# how insert data in the sqlite3 tables while checking if exist using python

Tags: python, sqlite, reddit, python-telegram-bot

i am trying to store the urerID and the urls they received, so i made a connector table `Receive` to save the ids of user and url.

There are 2 problems here:-

**First problem** :
The ids are not incremented not by 1 but by the number the code is executed multiplied by the number of urls sent, here this happen after user1 used the code twice : user1 typed in telegram chat `memes` twice and received 2 memes + 2 memes. then user2 used the bot.

[image]

**Second problem** :
How to check in `Receive` table for the existence of both `USER_ID` and `URL_ID` aka : know if the user received the memes ?

[image]

Here is the `URLS` table:

[image]

The Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS ( 
userID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
chatID INT(10) UNIQUE

);
CREATE TABLE URLS ( 
urlID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,
linkID TEXT UNIQUE 

);
CREATE TABLE Receive ( 
USER_ID INTEGER ,
URL_ID INTEGER ,
PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID , URL_ID)

)
```

the code:

```
def from_red():

for subm in reddit.subreddit('Memes').hot(limit=limit):

        urlId = subm.url[18:][:-4] 
        info = last_data('getUpdates')
        userid = get_chat_id(info)

        #curr.execute('SELECT USER_ID and URL_ID FROM Receive ')
        #e = curr.fetchone()

        curr.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO USERS (chatID) VALUES (?) ', (userid ,))
        curr.execute('SELECT userID FROM USERS WHERE chatID = ? ', (userid , ))
        id1 = curr.fetchone()[0]
        print(id1)

        curr.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO URLS (linkID) VALUES (?) ', (urlId ,))
        curr.execute('SELECT urlID FROM URLS WHERE linkID = ? ', (urlId , ))
        id2 = curr.fetchone()[0]
        print(id2)

        curr.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Receive (USER_ID , URL_ID) VALUES (? , ?)' ,(id1 , id2))


        send_pic(subm.url , subm.title)
        time.sleep(1.5)

        connection.commit()
```

Comment: doesn't `commit()` close the cursor?  Do you need a new cursor for the subsequent items in your iterator?

Comment: Don't combine `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY`. The latter implies the former.

Comment: no ```commit()``` doesn't close the cursor , ```close()``` does. i guess the problem is with the logic of the 2 table, i think ```fetchone()``` doesn't work for the second time , maybe because the ```SELECT``` statement is incorrect .

Comment: actually you're right ```UNIQUE``` and  ```PRIMARY KEY``` , make sure the the values are unique be default, but removing ```UNIQUE``` won't matter

Comment: i updated the post with what happens if 2 users use the bot

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're trying to use the same ID (the number 1) time after time again?

Comment: the id in the first table is a unique one (auto-inrement) , and suppose to be a FK to the userID in the second table

Comment: in which table do you fail to create more than one record?

Comment: the ```USERS``` table, also the urls in the second table is common for all the users which means that all the users will get the same number of urls (memes in this case) , i can tell you what i am trying to achieve here : i want to know if a certain user has received the pictures, by adding their chatID in a table and check if the urls have been sent, if you have a better implementation , i am happy to hear from you

Comment: It's better to think `users` table as `chat/users` table, it would have an autoincremental surrogate `ID` as primary key, the `chat_id` (from telegram) and `user_id` (from telegram). The other table would be `urls` where `url` works as primary and the other column would be `chat_id` (only if the url can exists in one chat, otherwise that table needs another autoincremental surrogate key as the primary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem (ids not incremented by 1) : i removed `usrID` and `urlID` and used the `rowid` instead

```
curr.executescript('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS ( 

chatID INT(10) UNIQUE,

);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS URLS ( 

linkID TEXT UNIQUE 

);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Receive ( 
USER_ID INTEGER ,
URL_ID INTEGER ,
PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID , URL_ID)

)

''')
```

The fixed codes:

```
curr.execute('SELECT rowid FROM USERS WHERE chatID = ? ', (userid , ))
id1 = curr.fetchone()[0]

curr.execute('SELECT rowid FROM URLS WHERE linkID = ? ', (urlId , ))
id1 = curr.fetchone()[0]
```

For the second problem (checking for userID and the urls) :

```
        try:
            curr.execute('INSERT INTO Receive (USER_ID , URL_ID) VALUES (? , ?)' ,(id1 , id2))
            send_pic(subm.url , subm.title)
            time.sleep(1.5)
            connection.commit()

        except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
            ...
            print('Anything else')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you keep inserting stuff with the same primary key. All users are inserted with `user-id = 1`. The line

```
curr.execute(
   'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO USERS (ID , chatID) VALUES (1 , ?) ', 
   (userid , ))
```

will use the value 1 for the user-id column of the table, and the value of the variable `userid` for chat-ID. The next time you'll try to insert a value to the table, it'll notice that the primary key '1' is already being used, and nothing will be inserted.

#### Update:

Only the first URL is inserted, as according to the log you're printing, you're almost always getting into the first branch of the `if` statement - the one with `print('exists')`. That's why you're not even trying to add new entries to the database.

Comment: i know that, and tried to update the ```USERS.ID``` after that and i messed everything

Comment: You're still trying to insert multiple users with the same ID.

Comment: i did update the id but only the first url is inserted

Comment: Edited my post. Which redit client package are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215568/discussion-between-ahmedo-and-roy2012).

Comment: hey there, i fixed some problems

Comment: @AhmedO - it seems to me that this quite different than the original question which was about records that are not being inserted to the 'users; table. Since that question is solved, the best approach would be to open a new  ***focused*** question about the issue you're currently dealing with. That would allow the most people to assist. If you'll tag me, I promise to have a look. (BTW - if my answered helped you' it would be great if you could accept it).

Comment: how to open a focused question ?

Comment: Create a new question. Have a look at this link about how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also - very important - make it minimal. See this link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i can't create new questions , i got banned from asking , idk why