# how to make the telegram bot know if a user has received the links?

Tags: database, sqlite, telegram-bot

i am trying to make a small database for my telegram bot to save users' IDs and the links(which are sent to them) to know if a user has received the links or not , all the users get the same number of links .

These are the tables i made

```
curr.executescript('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS URLS ( 
   id INT,
   link VARCHAR 

);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS ( 
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    chatID INT(10) UNIQUE,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES URLS(id)

)

''')
```

Comment: you should send a snippet from the bot code you've written instead (to make it easy for  others to help)

Comment: actually i did but on another question unfortunately no one answered , so i wanted to know what mistakes i have in my idea , i will fetch the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62234373/8958573

Comment: So, are you trying to check whether `send_pic(subm.url , subm.title)` has sent the message successfully?

Comment: yes, by adding userID (which i get from telegram) and memeURL in the database . I am doing this because when i fetch memes from Reddit the bot gets me from the beginning of the page , so there are duplicates